# Missing References After Installing ASP.NET 5

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I used the stand-alone method to install ASP.NET 5 from here: http://docs.asp.net/en/theming/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html

Now I have missing references, and I am not sure why. Anyone has any idea how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: make sure you install the latest beta7 tooling https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48738

Comment: @JoeAudette When I was trying to install WebToolsExtensionsVS14.msi, I get an error indicating that I don't have VS14, which is true, because I am using VS15. I don't know how to fix that. That's why I installed it manually.

Comment: VS14 is Visual Studio 2015. There is no VS15 yet. What do you mean by "you installed it manually"?

Comment: @opiants Oh. By manually I meant "Stand Alone." Sorry that was confusing.

Comment: There should be a project.lock.json in your project. Try expanding project.json if you can't find it. Can you delete that file? It should automatically restore the references after you do that. Might be totally unrelated but it shouldn't hurt to try it. It'll recreate that file if you delete it anyway.

Comment: @opiants There is no project.lock.json file there. I deleted project.json and nothing happened, plus project.json was not recreated automatically.Still not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Ooops. You should've never deleted project.json. I hope you have a back up. Project.json and project.lock.json serves similar but different purposes. What about running a [dnu restore](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/DNX-utility#restore-dnu-restore)?

Comment: Thank you @opiants dnu restore in the project directory fixed it!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @opiants, I found the answer.

I just ran the command "dnu restore" in the project directory. All the packages were automatically downloaded and the references were fixed.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in NuGet.